# Is there a bug with puppet and Centos 5.7?

Tags: centos, puppet

I'm going through the Puppet 'Learning' VM. Here's my manifest:

```
$ensure_val = 'present'

define student($full_name) {

  user { "${title}":
    ensure => $ensure_val,
    comment => "${full_name}",
    groups => "student",
    home => "/home/${title}",
    name => "${title}",
    password => "${title}",
    shell => "/bin/bash",
  }

}

$students = {
  'elion' => {full_name => "El Lion"},
  'azee' => {full_name => "Avery Zee"}
}

create_resources(student, $students)
```

When I do a `puppet apply manifest.pp`, it says that everything is created. I do a `cat /etc/shadow` and indeed those users are there. But doing an 'ls /home` shows an directory.

The VM is running on Centos 5.7. Is there something wrong with the puppet VM? Or am I doing something wrong in the manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  user { "${title}":
    ensure => $ensure_val,
    comment => "${full_name}",
    groups => "student",
    home => "/home/${title}",
    name => "${title}",
    password => "${title}",
    shell => "/bin/bash",
    managehome => true,
  }
```

Try adding managehome => true to your user resource, it should create the homedirs.